# Trying to connect snowflake using flyway-migration

Tags: java, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flyway, redgate

### `ERROR: Unable to determine the original schema for the connection`

```
SQL State  : XX000
Error Code : 200001
Message    : JDBC driver internal error: exception creating result java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.memory.UnsafeAllocationManager.<clinit>(UnsafeAllocationManager.java:27).

Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver internal error: exception creating result java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.memory.UnsafeAllocationManager.<clinit>(UnsafeAllocationManager.java:27).
```

I am getting the above error, it is successfully connecting to database and then I'm getting this error. I have set the schema in URL, checked for drivers and jars, and set the default schema as well in config file. I have replaced the jar with latest snowflake-jdbc jar , even then i am facing the same issue.

I want to connect to snowflake and migrate some tables.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Are you using a Java version above 16? Then have a look at [this article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/JDBC-Driver-Compatibility-Issue-With-JDK-16-and-Later).